# How do I check for two codes in xml list?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to know if a given product list contains two specific products. If both exist I need to ignore one. If only one of them exists I need to retain that product.

XML 1

```
<ns0:Items xmlns:ns0="abc">
  <ns0:Item>
    <ns0:Code>X1</ns0:Code> <!-- keep this because it is the only one -->
    <ns0:Quantity>1</ns0:Quantity>
  </ns0:Item>
</ns0:Items>
```

XML 2

```
<ns0:Items xmlns:ns0="abc">
  <ns0:Item>
    <ns0:Code>X1</ns0:Code> <!-- ignore this because we have another valid product -->
    <ns0:Quantity>1</ns0:Quantity>
  </ns0:Item>
  <ns0:Item>
    <ns0:Code>M1</ns0:Code>
    <ns0:Quantity>1</ns0:Quantity>
  </ns0:Item>
</ns0:Items>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="abc" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-16" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
  <xsl:template match="ns0:Items">
    <Items>
      <xsl:variable name="hasBoth">
        <xsl:value-of select="boolean(ns0:Item/ns0:Code[.='M1']) and boolean(ns0:Item/ns0:Code[.='X1'])" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Item">
        <xsl:variable name="validItem">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$hasBoth and ns0:Code='X1' and ns0:Quantity=1">
              <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <both>
          <xsl:value-of select="$hasBoth"/>
        </both>
        <expr>
          <xsl:value-of select="$hasBoth and ns0:Code='X1' and ns0:Quantity=1"/>
        </expr>
        <valid>
          <xsl:value-of select="$validItem"/>
        </valid>
        <xsl:if test="$validItem = 1">
          <SalesOrderDetail>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </SalesOrderDetail>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Items>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result 1 - this is wrong, it removes the X1 product even though it is the only one, how can $hasBoth be false AND expr be true?

```
<Items>
  <both>false</both>
  <expr>true</expr>
  <valid>0</valid>
</Items>
```

Result 2 - correct, it removes the X1 product

```
<Items>
  <both>true</both>
  <expr>true</expr>
  <valid>0</valid>
  <both>true</both>
  <expr>false</expr>
  <valid>1</valid>
  <SalesOrderDetail>
  </SalesOrderDetail>
</Items>
```

Comment: You have two inputs and two results, one of them is incorrect, how is the correct result 1 supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an issue with your `hasBoth` variable. When you use the `xsl:value-of` when you create it, the result is a string.

When you test `$hasBoth` it is true even when the string value is "false" because:

```
boolean("false") = true()
```

Also, you shouldn't need to use `boolean()`.

Try changing this:

```
<xsl:variable name="hasBoth">
  <xsl:value-of select="boolean(ns0:Item/ns0:Code[.='M1']) and boolean(ns0:Item/ns0:Code[.='X1'])" />
</xsl:variable>
```

to this:

```
<xsl:variable name="hasBoth" 
        select="ns0:Item/ns0:Code[.='M1'] and ns0:Item/ns0:Code[.='X1']"/>
```

Comment: you'd think that having experience with javascript would have taught me to be sure I was comparing types correctly!!! Thanks.